# render doc in exposures description in dbt

Tags: dbt

I have exposures written under sources.yml file under models folder

```
exposures:
  - name: data_sources
    description: '{{ doc("orders_status") }}'
    type: dashboard
    url: urlname
  
    owner:
      name: name
      email: mailid
```

I also have docs.md under models folder which has

```
{% docs orders_status %}

Orders can be one of the following statuses:

| status         | description                                                               |
|----------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| placed         | The order has been placed but has not yet left the warehouse              |
| shipped        | The order has ben shipped to the customer and is currently in transit     |
| completed      | The order has been received by the customer                               |
| returned       | The order has been returned by the customer and received at the warehouse |


{% enddocs %}
```

when I perform dbt docs generate, I get

```
Encountered an error:
Compilation Error
  Failed to render models\sources.yml from project cemd_transformations: Compilation Error
    Could not render {{ doc("orders_status") }}: 'doc' is undefined
```

Is there any other thing I should include to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

That's a known issue that got fixed in `v0.19.0`. So, if possible, I recommend you upgrade your dbt version.

There are topics in the documentation on how to do that:

https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/installation

Also, there is a migration guide where they pointed out some **breaking changes**. They don't expect these to require action in most of the projects, but it's important to be aware of it:

https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/migration-guide/upgrading-to-0-19-0

#### Closed Issues

https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/3030

https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/2913